# Calendar event invites not updating

Tags: apex, calendar

One of the requirements that I should do is sending calendar invites and updates when an event/task is created/edited. I found that this is possible by sending an email with an .ics attachment.

The problem is that once I send an invite, I can not send an updated invite(in case if an event has been rescheduled for example).

I've got a method that creates a `Blob` that I will use as body attachment:

```
public static Blob generateEvent(String recepient, String summary, String description, Datetime startDate, Datetime endDate, String uniqueId, Integer seqNr) {
    // Build date strings
    String startDateString = '';
    startDateString += startDate.year();
    startDateString += ('0' + startDate.month()).right(2);
    startDateString += ('0' + startDate.day()).right(2);
    startDateString += 'T';
    startDateString += ('0' + startDate.hour()).right(2);
    startDateString += ('0' + startDate.minute()).right(2);
    startDateString += ('0' + startDate.second()).right(2);
    startDateString += 'Z';

    String endDateString = '';
    endDateString += endDate.year();
    endDateString += ('0' + endDate.month()).right(2);
    endDateString += ('0' + endDate.day()).right(2);
    endDateString += 'T';
    endDateString += ('0' + endDate.hour()).right(2);
    endDateString += ('0' + endDate.minute()).right(2);
    endDateString += ('0' + endDate.second()).right(2);
    endDateString += 'Z';

    String nowString = '';
    Datetime nowDT = Datetime.now();
    nowString += nowDT.year();
    nowString += ('0' + nowDT.month()).right(2);
    nowString += ('0' + nowDT.day()).right(2);
    nowString += 'T';
    nowString += ('0' + nowDT.hour()).right(2);
    nowString += ('0' + nowDT.minute()).right(2);
    nowString += ('0' + nowDT.second()).right(2);
    nowString += 'Z';

    // Generate actual body
    String txtInvite = '';
    txtInvite += 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n';
    txtInvite += 'PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN\n';
    txtInvite += 'VERSION:2.0\n';
    txtInvite += 'CALSCALE:GREGORIAN\n';
    txtInvite += 'METHOD:REQUEST\n';
    txtInvite += 'BEGIN:VEVENT\n';
    txtInvite += 'DTSTART:' + startDateString + '\n';
    txtInvite += 'DTEND:' + endDateString + '\n';
    txtInvite += 'DTSTAMP:' + startDateString + '\n';
    txtInvite += 'ORGANIZER;CN=' + UserInfo.getUserName() + ':MAILTO:' + UserInfo.getUserEmail() + '\n';
    txtInvite += 'UID:' + uniqueId + '\n';
    txtInvite += 'ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=\n';
    txtInvite += ' TRUE;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:' + recepient + '\n';
    txtInvite += 'CREATED:' + nowString + '\n';
    txtInvite += 'DESCRIPTION:' + description + '\n';
    txtInvite += 'LAST-MODIFIED:' + nowString + '\n';
    txtInvite += 'LOCATION:TBD\n';
    if (seqNr != null) {
        txtInvite += 'SEQUENCE:' + seqNr + '\n';
    }
    txtInvite += 'STATUS:CONFIRMED\n';
    txtInvite += 'SUMMARY:' + summary + '\n';
    txtInvite += 'TRANSP:OPAQUE\n';
    txtInvite += 'END:VEVENT\n';
    txtInvite += 'END:VCALENDAR\n';

    return Blob.valueOf(txtInvite);
}
```

And then I try to send it from developer console:

```
Blob fileBody = UTIL_EmailGenerator.generateEvent('my_email_address@blabla.com', 'summary', 'description', Datetime.now().addHours(1), Datetime.now().addHours(2), 'testEvent1', 0);

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'my_email_address@blabla.com'};
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
mail.setSubject('Subject mail');
mail.setPlainTextBody('');
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
attach.filename = 'meeting.ics';
attach.ContentType = 'text/calendar;';
attach.inline = true;
attach.body = fileBody;
mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {attach});
Messaging.SendEmailResult[] er = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Email[] {mail});
```

First time I send it, the result is as expected:

[image]

However, if I want to update this event and if I change the start and end dates and increment sequence number, I still get the exact same invite!

**So the question is:**

How can I send an update to already existing event?

Comment: Just checked your code in my DE and its working just fine. :) I got the event created and when I changed the Start and End time, it is updated properly.

Comment: doesn't work for me though...

Comment: This may be an issue with your Google Calendar settings.

Comment: Make sure to keep the UID dynamic. It will work.